# Invertiblity of sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

Assume two matrices *A* and *B* are both symmetric positive definite. I was wondering whether *I+AB* and *I-AB* are invertible, where *I* is the identity matrix. (A hint might
be *AB* is positive definite iff *AB* is symmetric.)

Comment: if $A=B=I$ then $I-AB=0$

Comment: Oh yes. What if we exclude this special case? Assume that this is not the case

Comment: No, in general you will not have $I-AB$ invertible. Pick $A=\begin{bmatrix}1.5 & -0.5\\-0.5 & 1.5\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}0.75 & 0.25\\0.25 & 0.75\end{bmatrix}$. It is not a pathological example.

Comment: $I-AB$ is not invertible when $AB$ has eigenvalue 1.

Comment: anyway, a trick to prove the first one is to remember that any PD matrix has a square root that is again a PD matrix

Comment: Consider $B(I+AB)$.

Comment: @KBS I see. Thanks for that.

Comment: @user1551 Could you give more hints on how to use B(I+AB)?

Comment: @Stephanie Expand $B(I+AB)$ and show that it is invertible.